# Client-WebService solution: where to store login data?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, client, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a market. This market will be used from Browsers, Desktop App, mobile devices, and any stuff that can be a client.

My problem is about layers and architecture. I thought that it will be a good way to write a full web api layer and then call any action of that by any client. Because of this idea I started developing even the browser part as I said and my web site (asp mvc) is a client just as others.

The real problem is where to store the User Data after login? I was thinking of storing them in web api layer. But as I started to develop, I found that asp web api is a RESTful one and is stateless.

Now, what is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Local Storage of your clients' browser.
Store a token in local storage and make your calls to your stateless api with the token from your client side.

This should help you
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: So, isn't it bad to make stateless api, state sensitive this way? And then what is the best way to make Token and where to store that token on server(api)?

Comment: why would you make your api state sensitive? Save your user data in your database and on the client side when necessary. I'll edit the answer and add a link which might help you for an Authorization Provider to integrate into your API which you basically need.